# Mount hard disk restricting permissions to particular users

Tags: mount, permissions, hard-drive, users, 17.04

How can I set one of my internal hard drives to automount at boot but with selective permissions? I would like my wife and I to have full access to it, but make it unavailable to the children's accounts. It is formatted as EXT4 and I am using Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: This is not an issue with mounting but about discretionary user access control of the files on the file system itself. Do you, your wife, and your children have individual accounts or do you share a single one? If you have at least two accounts, one for you and your wife and for your children, that can be achieved easily. Zanna's answer goes in that direction but I'd like to ask for more specific information because you may not know how to set up new users and access restriction for them.

Comment: Everyone has their own individual  accounts and the children do not have sudo.  The drive is only for data storage - mainly photos and music. Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you only want to use this drive to store data. I'm also assuming your kids don't have `sudo` - obviously all bets are off if they do.

Choose a mount point for the drive and create it, for example

```
sudo mkdir /media/stuff
```

If the drive is already in your `/etc/fstab`, modify the line to use this mountpoint. You will need to use `sudo` to edit the file. Please make a backup copy before editing. See [the fstab wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) for more information.

If the drive is not in `/etc/fstab`, then add a line for it. First run

```
sudo blkid
```

And get the UUID for the drive. This is a long ugly string of characters. The new `fstab` line should be something like:

```
UUID=long-string-of-chars-from-blkid  /media/stuff  ext4 defaults 0 2
```

Now just set permissions on the mountpoint so that only root has execute permission on it. If a user has no execute permission on a directory, they cannot enter it or any directory below it.

```
sudo chmod 700 /media/stuff
```

Now add ACL permissions for yourself and your wife (replace `me` and `mywife` with the proper usernames).

```
sudo setfacl -m me:rwx /media/stuff
sudo setfacl -m mywife:rwx /media/stuff
```

Comment: Thankyou @Zanna, that worked and the drive mounted at boot but I also had to do

Comment: `sudo setfacl -x child1 /media/stuff`

Comment: Initially, when the drive fist mounted after I edited fstab, everybody had access. I never knew about the setfacl command. The commands above fixed it though.  I've learned something today. thanks once again.

Comment: @David42 ah great that you got it working how you want :)